Sum fields of a vector depending on condition and get a smaller vector
Let's say I have this struct:
pub struct MyStruct {
    uuid: uuid,
    date: NaiveDate,
    value1: i32,
    value2: i32
    my_type: i8
}

I am looking for a way to combine a vector of this MyStruct so that it does not repeat (pseudocode):
  let all_structs: Vec<MyStruct> = vec![MyStruct, MyStruct , MyStruct ...];
  let structs_per_uuid_and_date = all_structs.into_iter(). { sum specific fields (like value1 and value2) for same combination of uuid and date }


and we discard my_type

What do you mean by "same combination of uuid and date"? Do you mean uuid == X && date == Y?

meaning that if the same uuid and date show up their values have to be merged, we discard the field my_type that we don't required anymore

If I understand correctly, a better description of what you're after is to "merge duplicates".

So this is essentially a groupby agg?

Yes it is what I use with the SQL request, I was curious how to do it with Rust. There are also other ways (to do it with Rust) than the accepted answer.

You can do this by sorting the Vec and then using dedup_by.
use chrono::NaiveDate;
use uuid::Uuid;

pub struct MyStruct {
    uuid: Uuid,
    date: NaiveDate,
    value1: i32,
    value2: i32,
    my_type: i8,
}

pub fn merge(structs: &mut Vec<MyStruct>) {
    structs.sort_by_key(|s| (s.uuid, s.date));
    structs.dedup_by(|a, b| {
        if a.uuid == b.uuid && a.date == b.date {
            b.value1 += a.value1;
            b.value2 += a.value2;
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    })
}

You can't discard a field of a struct.

Better to use sort_unstable_by_key() if coming first doesn't matter. Also, this is O(N*lg(N)). An O(N) alternative will be to collect into a HashMap.
